# Not able to parse Json using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm trying to display results in an android app that parses JSON but when I try to parse the JSON with Retrofit, I end up with null fields apart from the field concept. My code is down below.

Observation Class

```
public class Observation extends Resource implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("concept")
    @Expose
    private Concept concept;

    @SerializedName("person")
    @Expose
    private Person person;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("value")
    private List<Object> value;



    public Concept getConcept() {
        return concept;
    }


    public void setConcept(Concept concept) {
        this.concept = concept;
    }


    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }


    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }   

    public List<Object> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Object> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

My Retrofit interface

```
public interface MyApiEndPointsInterface {
  @GET("/obs/{id}")
  Call<Observation> getObservation(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

And the code in the activity

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyApiEndPointsInterface apiService =
            retrofit.create(MyApiEndPointsInterface.class);

    Call<Observation> call = apiService.getObservation(76341);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Observation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Observation> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", response.body().value.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
t.printStacktrace();
        }
    });
```

The JSON object returned by the server is this

```
{
    "concept": {
        "uuid": "46d4283e-3275-4c6e-9d52-cfd858889f4b",
        "display": "HDU stay during admission",
        "name": {
            "display": "HDU stay during admission",
            "uuid": "1be0302e-72fe-444c-bf0c-b92aed0c3f85",
            "name": "HDU stay during admission",
            "locale": "en",
            "localePreferred": true,
            "conceptNameType": "FULLY_SPECIFIED",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/concept/46d4283e-3275-4c6e-9d52-cfd858889f4b/name/1be0302e-72fe-444c-bf0c-b92aed0c3f85"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "full",
                    "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/concept/46d4283e-3275-4c6e-9d52-cfd858889f4b/name/1be0302e-72fe-444c-bf0c-b92aed0c3f85?v=full"
                }
            ],
            "resourceVersion": "1.9"
        }
    },
    "person": {
        "uuid": "24d85b48-ef69-4de0-91a4-e751bda85332",
        "display": "103 - Gavana Test Nkaiseri",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/patient/24d85b48-ef69-4de0-91a4-e751bda85332"
            }
        ]
    },
    "value": {
        "uuid": "1066AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "display": "No",
        "name": {
            "display": "No",
            "uuid": "1138BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
            "name": "No",
            "locale": "en",
            "localePreferred": true,
            "conceptNameType": "FULLY_SPECIFIED",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/concept/1066AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/name/1138BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "full",
                    "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/concept/1066AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/name/1138BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB?v=full"
                }
            ],
            "resourceVersion": "1.9"
        },
        "datatype": {
            "uuid": "8d4a4c94-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f",
            "display": "N/A",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/conceptdatatype/8d4a4c94-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f"
                }
            ]
        },
        "conceptClass": {
            "uuid": "8d492774-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f",
            "display": "Misc",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "uri": "http://10.10.0.2/ws/rest/v1/conceptclass/8d492774-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f"
                }
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show your exception

Comment: There is no exception. Just a null value

Comment: why you are taking value as a list of object..

Comment: take it as private Value value.. and define and define values as a separate Pojo

Comment: deserialization issue clearly

Comment: which specific fields are coming null  ???

Comment: @Kriti so that I can cast the object to anything I would like

Comment: @Roy all but Concept

Comment: use this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ link to create Observation class. i think your created class is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complex json structures, don't rely on json to pojo generators. Do it by hand. Your POJO class has a few errors. Also when you use the `GsonConverterFactory` you don't need getters and setters, just make the fields public. These models will deserialize correctly (I named the root class `JsonObj` because I didn't know what kind of data we are dealing with):

```
public class Observation {
    public Concept concept;
    public DataDescription person;
    public Value value;
}

public class Concept {
    public String uuid;
    public String display;
    public Name name;
}

public class Name {
    public String uuid;
    public String display;
    public String name;
    public String locale;
    public String localePreferred;
    public String conceptNameType;
    public Link[] links;
    public String resourceVersion;
}

public class Link {
    public String rel;
    public String uri;
}

public class DataDescription {
    public String uuid;
    public String display;
    public Link[] links;
}

public class Value {
    public String uuid;
    public String display;
    public Name name;
    public DataDescription datatype;
    public DataDescription conceptClass;
}
```

You can then deserialize this like so in your Retrofit interface:

```
 Call<Observation> getObservation(@Path("id") String id);
```

See:[image: parsed json]

Comment: "when you use the GsonConverterFactory you don't need getters and setters, just make the fields public" => sounds good to me but is not it violating the convention to follow?

Comment: I guess it does break convention. However, in this case, you are merely representing the json data in java object form - this object is most likely not going to be manipulated (depending on your use case). In my opinion that makes it redundant to add in this scenario.